# installs failing via yum with large files and slow connection

Tags: linux, yum, rhel, package-managers

I have a situation where I need to run yum from a site that has a slow "about 50kbps" intermittent  connection. For packages smaller than 40M (our unscientifically determined threshold) yum seems to eventually get the job done but anything larger will eventually stall out and not work. So far I haven't been able to figure out the magical configuration to get this working properly. I'd like to know if anyone has some suggestions on what I could do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using yumdownloader to retrieve the rpm(s), and then yum to install the already downloaded rpms.